# What is the best way to store special characters in a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a system set up that records if a document has been read or not to later be displayed in a nice little chart. I'd like to use a simple ✓ (&#x2713 ;), but I don't know how to go about doing this. Would it be best for me to store a PHP variable in the database and define it on the display page? If so, how would I go about doing this? Maybe there's a much better way I haven't thought of? I'd rather not have to stitch things together in a sketchy way just for a little check mark.

Comment: Store a boolean field and use an `if` statement to pick a character?

Comment: I would do as you suggest, store some value in the db that you recognise as that character then let the template handle the display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way is to save boolean in you database and to check :

```
if($res == 1) { return "&#x2713"} - as example
```

Answer (score 2):

Just store any character as is. It's apparently the best way for storing any data.

However, regarding your particular question, there shouldn't be no characters but just a boolean value. Wile whatever decoration have to be programmed in the **template**